# Default values of Kafka log.flush.interval.messages and log.flush.interval.ms when they are commented in config file

Tags: apache-kafka

I wonder what values of log.flush.interval.messages and log.flush.interval.ms are when I leave them commented in Kafka server config file? Are there any default values?

Comment: Well. I found it in Kafka documentation with simple google search :P Look [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#configuration)

Comment: thanks :) ---
well. I found this stackoverflow question with a simple google search :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @running.t's [link](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#configuration) provides, the answers are

```
log.flush.interval.messages = Long.MaxValue
log.flush.interval.ms = Long.MaxValue
```